# How to Validate Table Daily

Tags: jquery, sql, pentaho

I currently am importing data daily into my table. How can i assure myself that all data is getting imported daily except Saturdays and Sundays? Would i have to create a separate calendar table and compare my table to that? Seems tedious updating the calendar every year.

FYI,
i Am using pentaho data integration to import data into my tables. I was thinking there should be some type of query with cases? If date is not in table then use that variable to trigger myself an email?

Notice i am missing 10/30 and 10/31..i would of never known unless i do a query and group by date to see my missing dates that did not get imported.

current table:

```
DATE    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME     AGE
10/28    Chris        Perez          30
10/29    Manuel       Gonzalez       31
11/1     John        Johnson         34
11/2     Chris         Archie        24
```

thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you want to make such a check?

Comment: your question has multiple meanings, edit your question, what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PDI, you can use filters before executing the KTR that executes the table imports.

Something like this should do it.

[image]

You only need to change the text of START WITH in the filter to match your language

IE.: Sat - Saturday and Sun - Sunday

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question it depends how you have implemented your solution. If you are doing Full truncate load then validating source file rows to data table rows can be and easier way to check it.maintaining historic record counts won't matter much as source system will have rows adding/deleting  and comparing it with previous date does not help you.

For the next part of your question if you are reliant on this table do an evaluation check at the end of the day if the data is not equal to business run date then shoot an email.May be you need to revisit error handling ,logging and notification as part of your etl to make it more interactive.